# Convert data from Google Analytics into last 12 months

Tags: java, primefaces, google-analytics

I've got a primefaces/Java application that gets the last 12 months data that I'm putting into a chart.

I've got the data in months i.e. 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.

I want to show this as the last 12 months, i.e. say it's currently June -

July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June.

I'm assuming I'll need to convert the Chart series data and resort it, any ideas how?

Here's the current function:

```
    public List<VisitByPath2> getVisitsChartData() throws Exception {

    DataQuery query = gaService.newQuery(startDate, endDate, 100);
    query.setDimensions("ga:month");
    query.setMetrics("ga:visits,ga:visitsWithEvent");
    query.setFilters(getGuideFilter());
    query.setSort("ga:month");
    List<DataEntry> data = gaService.executeQuery(query);

    List<VisitByPath2> visits = new ArrayList<VisitByPath2>();

    visitChart = new CartesianChartModel(); 
        ChartSeries visitorsData = new ChartSeries();  
        ChartSeries activeVisitorsData = new ChartSeries();  
        visitorsData.setLabel("Inactive Visitors");
        activeVisitorsData.setLabel("Active Visitors");

        for (DataEntry visit : data) {
            VisitByPath2 visitChartData = new VisitByPath2(visit);

            visits.add(new VisitByPath2(visit));
            visitorsData.set(visitChartData.getMonth(),visitChartData.getVisitsWithOutEvents());
            activeVisitorsData.set(visitChartData.getMonth(),visitChartData.getVisitsWithEvent());
        }

        visitChart.addSeries(activeVisitorsData);
        visitChart.addSeries(visitorsData);

    return visits;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using yearMonth rather than Month, and converting that into a date using SimpleDateFormat.